# Adding texture to Cast Shadows in Blender 2.8/2.9 Eevee

Tags: node-editor, shadows

I have been researching if there is a way to add textures to cast shadows in Eevee. I found what I was looking for on Youtube but it only works in Cycles.

Here is the Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA88laLTEIo

Is there a way to control the textures on a Cast Shadow?

Answer (score 0):

The 'shadow ray' is not properly implemented in eevee. There is no alternative for it.